# Array of strings and ints in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, tuples

I am trying to make an array of arrays where each nested array has a string and an integer.

I have seen you can use structs but all I want to do is make them a constant, and I want to know if there is a way to do it without having to type loads of extra stuff

```
let items: [[String, Int]] = [["A", 1], ["B", 2], ["C", 3]]
```

Comment: 1. Those aren't tuples. Why is this tagged with tuples? 2. What extra stuff are you referring to? Your question is not clear at all.

Comment: How is it not clear? I want to mix strings and ints in an array.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think what you want is an array of tuples, not an array of arrays.  That implementation would look like this:

```
let items: [(String, Int)] = [("A", 1), ("B", 2), ("C", 3)]
```

You could access these properties like this:

```
let itemOneString = items[0].0 // "A"
let itemOneInt = items[0].1 // 1
```

Answer (score 1):

It will work for you:

`let items: [[(String, Int)]] = [[("A", 1)], [("B", 2)], [("C", 3)]]`

Comment: Why the extra layer of array? Why not simply have an array of tuples instead of an array of arrays of tuple?

Comment: @rmaddy why not to have struct instead of tuple? It's way more representative rather then just a tuple

Comment: Ask the OP, not me. I agree a struct is better. But that has nothing to do with your answer which has a needless extra layer of arrays.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Array is collection of similar data types. It can not contain heterogeneous types data.

But if you still want to do it. There are other workarounds like create array of `dictionary` like this.

```
let items: [[String: Any]] = [["String" : "A", "Int" : 1], ["String" : "B", "Int" : 2]]
```

or create an array of `Tuples`.

```
let items: [(String, Int)] = [("A", 1), ("B", 2), ("C", 3)]
```

You can add any number of items in `Tuple` or `Dictionary`.